# Create XML file in Python using minidom (more than one parented element)

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I'm currently attempting to create a double-parented XML file within Python using minidom, however I'm struggling to get it to work (and by struggling I mean it's not)

I'm trying to create something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<twitter>
    <account>
        <name>Triple J</name>
        <handle>triplejplays</handle>
        <format>.{artist} - {title} [{time}]</format>
    </account>
    <account>
        <name>BBC Radio 1</name>
        <handle>BBCR1MusicBot</handle>
        <format>Now Playing {artist} - {title}</format>
    </account>
</twitter>
```

Using this code:

```
def createXML():
    #Define document
    xmlFile = Document()

    #Create base element
    baseElement = xmlFile.createElement("twitter")

    #Create account element
    accountElement = xmlFile.createElement("account")

    #Append account element to base element
    baseElement.appendChild(accountElement)

    #Create elements and content under account
    nameElement = xmlFile.createElement("name")
    nameContent = xmlFile.createTextNode("Triple J")
    nameContent.appendChild(nameElement)
    nameElement.appendChild(accountElement)

    handleElement = xmlFile.createElement("handle")
    handleContent = xmlFile.createTextNode("triplejplays")
    handleContent.appendChild(handleElement)
    handleElement.appendChild(accountElement)

    formatElement = xmlFile.createElement("format")
    formatContent = xmlFile.createTextNode(".{artist} - {title} [{time}]")
    formatContent.appendChild(formatElement)
    formatElement.appendChild(formatElement)

    print(doc.toxml(encoding='utf-8'))

createXML()
```

But I get this error:

```
Text nodes cannot have children
```

Is there any way to make this work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of e.g. `nameContent.appendChild(nameElement)` you need e.g `nameElement.appendChild(nameContent)` as you need to append the text node create to the element node created earlier.